# Message is received several times from gcm

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

When notification is received I send a broadcast, using this code.

```
Event event = requestManager.getEventById(comment.eventId);
        Intent intent = new Intent(NOTIFICATION_ACTION).putExtra(EventFragment.EVENT, event);
        builder.setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
```

The broadcast opens different activities, when the app is running or not.

```
    public class NotificationBroadCastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Event event = intent.getParcelableExtra(EventFragment.EVENT);
        if (event != null) {
            if (MainActivity.isRunning()) {
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putParcelable(EventFragment.EVENT, event);
                intent = OneFragmentActivity.getStartIntent(context, EventFragment.class, args, R.layout.toolbar);
            } else {
                intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(MainActivity.COMMENT_NOTIFICATION_EVENT, event);
            }
        }
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

When I click on the notification, when the app is running everything is working as expected. But when I kill the application and open the notification. The activity is opened as expected, but the same notification is received again.

Here is a gcm service code.

```
public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService {

    public static final String NOTIFICATION_ACTION = "com.khevents.Notification";

    private void setupCommentNotification(Comment comment, Notification.Builder builder) throws IOException {
        RequestManager requestManager = EventsApp.getInstance().getRequestManager();

        VkUser vkUser = requestManager.getVkUserById(comment.userId);
        builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapUtilities.getBitmapFromURL(vkUser.avatar));
        builder.setContentTitle(vkUser.name + " " + vkUser.lastName);
        builder.setContentText(comment.text);

        Event event = requestManager.getEventById(comment.eventId);
        Intent intent = new Intent(NOTIFICATION_ACTION).putExtra(EventFragment.EVENT, event);
        builder.setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
    }

    private Notification.Builder createNotification(GCMData data) throws IOException {
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
        if (data.comment != null) {
            setupCommentNotification(data.comment, builder);
        }
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.add_icon);
        return builder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle bundle) {
        super.onMessageReceived(from, bundle);
        String json = bundle.getString("data");
        Log.i("GCM", "message received: " + json);
        GCMData data = Json.readNoThrow(json, GCMData.class);
        if (data == null) {
            return;
        }

        try {
            Notification.Builder notification = createNotification(data);

            new Handler(getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    postNotification(notification);
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void postNotification(Notification.Builder builder) {
        Notifications.notify(this, 1, builder);
    }
}
```

Comment: You mention that the same notification is triggered again after you launch the application. It sounds like this issue might be associated with your GCM Broadcast Receiver. Could you post the code associated with that?

Comment: Yes. Just posted it. I am using standard GcmListenerService for receiving notifications.

Comment: Check if your android app register again on each application launch (get new token)? And check your server app if whenever there is new client token (device id) then re-send message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. I started GcmListenerService manually, but I shouldn't do this. The problem was fixed after removing startService code.

Answer (score 0):

try to set flag to FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

```
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```